# How to embed video url for ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {   

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:<html><head>\
    <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>\
    <body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\">\
    <div><object width=\"100\" height=\"100\">\
    <param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param>\
    <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>\
    <embed src=\"%@\"\
    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\"></embed>\
    </object></div></body></html>",url,url];

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:TRUE];
    [webView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

}
```

I have implemented above code. It works fine on iPhone, but on iPad I just hear the audio, the video is not displayed.

How can I make this work on both types of devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution after working more then two days...
Solution is that I need to add controller in view not same as iphone.
But remember one thing just write this two line while dismissing view.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick. try the following code:

(mind you, it will work only on the device and not the simulator)

```
  NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/iyKsSPHM0wE"];



    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil]; 
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache]; [sharedCache release];
    //

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: videoURL cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 30.0];  
    [webView loadRequest: request];  
    [request release];
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but it can't help like this because it can't play video directly in player just like implement above code and play it in device(real iphone or iPod).